# как поменять разрешение видео python?

Tags: python, moviepy

У меня есть видеоролик, как я могу поменять уменьшить его масштаб(поменять разрешение) с помощью python?
p.s.moviepy.editor resize не работает

Comment: gstreamer  или ffmpeg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

очень хитро с этим методом resize долго бился в итоге получилось.

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, vfx

                    # Загружаем видео с диска
                    intermediate_clip = VideoFileClip(output_path_intermediate)

                    # Изменяем размеры загруженного видео
                    final_clip_resized = intermediate_clip.resize((1080, 1920))
```

НО! самое интересное в том что мой код работает на одном компе и не работает на другом. Библиотеки и модули все одинаковые, но на одном из компов код виснет именно на этой строке и не выполняет изменение размера видео, а на другом отрабатывает без проблем.

Comment: Спасибо, уже сам разобрался с проблемой. Мне кажется, что код может не работает на разных компьютерах из-за разных версий ffmpeg (на базе которого и работает moviepy)